# iPhone video stream from rails server not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, json-web-token

I have been facing one issue, I need to stream a video inside an iPhone app from rails server. While sending streaming request i need to set the request header which is a jwt token for authentication.

1. Tried  to use iPhone builtin component `MPMoviePlayerController`, but problem is I’m not able to set the header because it only takes NSURL instead NSURLRequest.
2. Also tried to achieve this by using `UIWebView` by creating `NSURLRequest` with request header and load into Webview.  I’m able to stream video for the first time when i freshly build and run the app. But after that its doesn’t streaming ( Because while streaming it send request multiple times and only for first request it set the header and not for subsequent request). If i  reinstall the app, again it works for the first run.

Code look like this:

```
NSString * jwtToken = @“Token”; 
NSString * Bearer = @"Bearer ";
NSString *authHeader=[Bearer stringByAppendingString:jwtToken];
[urlRequest setValue:authHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
urlRequest.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
webview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
webview.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
webview.opaque = NO;
webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[webview setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
webview.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:webview];
[webview loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

I have some doubts,
1. Is there a way to use iPhone builtIn video component  with request header?
2.  If i need to use UIwebView, how can i solve this problem?

Please guide me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try `AVPlayer` of `AVFoundation` with only url. It will manage other thing i think. you will not need to set any type of header or anything else. you can play video from remote video via `AVPlayer`.

You can do something like,

```
   NSString *urlString = @"yourUrlStrong";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
self.item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:self.item];
AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
 //    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoPlayingFinished:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:self.item];
playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
playerLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
[self.player play];
self.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
```

And make sure that you are declaring `AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerItem` as property not local variable.

Comment: Thanks ketan for your answer, But i need to set header because server needs that to serve video.

Comment: what error you are getting if you directly try to play video from url only ??

Comment: server will not serve video. because to authenticate it needs that token to be set.

Comment: I can't use only url.

Comment: your server should support `byte range` to stream video in ios and then you not need to set header. second for live streaming you should prepare your server like it can serve video direct from url, i mean no authentication or header should require!!!

Comment: Yes, I'm using byte range in server  which is working if i disable the authentication. But for some reason authentication need to implement in server side.